# Sidekiq Continue when complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I want to do this:

```
def perform
  # do some stuff

  Run 10 other workers in parallel

  # do some more stuff when all 10 are finished
end
```

How would I do this in Sidekiq? I thought I may add those ten to a custom queue, and then check to see when that queue is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this page: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects#execution-ordering could help.

Also sounds like typical [Sidekiq Pro](http://sidekiq.org/pro/) use case.